# Why is my loop always running only one time?

Tags: c++, c, loops, logic, digits

actually am a beginner in c programming and I was trying to find out the sum of digits of a number. I developed a logic and my code was:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{

int n;
int count= 0;
int x = 0;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
float a = n;

while (n != 0) // knowing the number of digits in the number
{
n = n/10;
count = count+1;

}
printf("The number of digits are: %d \n", count);
float loop = count * 10;

for (float i = 10.0; i<=loop; i = i*10.0) // loop to find out the sum of numbers
{
float b = a/i;
int c = a/i;
float d = b-c;
int e = d*10;
x = x + e;

}
printf ("The sum of digits is: %d", x);
return 0;
}
```

note :

My logic in this program = suppose user enters **12** then at first, the value of **n** will be assigned to **a** and the number of digits will be  **2**  (The first while loop is correct, problem is with the second for loop). In the second loop (for loop), **b** will assign **1.2** and **c** will assign **1**, then **d** will assign **0.2** (the difference of b and c). After that, **e** will be **0.2 x 10** which equals to **2** and **x** will be **0 + 2** which equals to **2**. Similarly, I expect the loop to run 2nd time and store **0.1** and **0** in **b** and **c** respectively (the value of **i** is being increased by **i * 10.0**)but the loop is just running one time and giving the output 2 .

*I know that this is not the best logic for the program and in fact wasn't working as I expected but while debugging a little I found out that the second loop (for loop) is just running  once, no matter how many numbers were inputed. I found some another logic to solve this program and it is working but still I want to know what is happening here and why the output is not as I expected.
Thank you for reading..*

new logic :

```
   // this program is working
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,count;
    int x = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    float a = n;
    
    while (n != 0) // knowing the number of digits in the number
    {
    n = n/10;
    count ++;
    
    }
    printf("The number of digits are: %d \n", count);
    float j = 10.0;
    for (int i = 1; i<=count; i++)
    {
    float b = a/j;
    int c = a/j;
    float d = b-c;
    int e = d*10;
    x = x + e;
    j = j*10.0;
    
    }
    printf ("The sum of digits is: %d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to debug! Take the debugger and step through the program.

Comment: ...and please format your code blocks by indenting them

Comment: If there's 5 digits, then `count` is 5, and `loop` is 50. In your second loop, `i` increases by a factor of 10 each time, so takes the values 1, then 10, then 100 (stopping). I guess you wanted `loop` to be `pow(10, count)` instead of `10*count` although using floating point is often a bad idea when you want exact integer arithmetic.

Comment: regarding `for (float i = 10.0; i<=loop; i = i*10.0)`  1) 'i' is a float, but '10.0' is a double..  the result is a lot of implicit conversions between `float` and `double`  If your compiler did not warn you of lots of implicit conversion problems in your code, then enable the warnings. I.E.  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=C11`

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one bug: the line

```
float loop = count * 10;
```

must be replaced by

```
 float loop = pow(10,count);
```

The `pow` function is in

```
#include <math.h>
```

and you will have to link with the math library `libm.so`, under linux this means:

```
gcc prog.c -lm
```

With this modification an input of 123 returns 6 as expected

Comment: oh god! thank  you sir....I was searching for the mistake and it was just a simple one. thank you once again

Comment: sir why are we replacing float loop = count * 10; with float loop = pow(10,count); what is happening with the loop? I was watching the program after a few days and was confused in this

Answer (score 2):

The variable `loop` should be assigned the value of 10 raised to the power of the value of `count` and not the product. However, there are some issues with the program :

Developing a logic that involves 2 loops whereas only one could have solved the problems is poor practice, even if it is for educational purposes. A simpler approach would have been stepping through the number from reverse order (i.e., beginning at the last digit and moving onto the front) and adding each digit as we iterate. The code for that would be :

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main () {
    int n, sum = 0;
    printf("Enter a natural number = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n != 0)
    {
        sum += (n % 10);
        n /= 10;
    }
    printf("The sum of digits is = %d", sum);
}
```

And if it is an absolute necessity to implement your logic, I will suggest the following modification (which does not involve the use of the standard library, except for I/O. Often in educational institutions, use of the standard library for purposes other than I/O is not allowed, so the following solution is given) :

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {

  int n;
  int count = 0;
  int x = 0;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  float a = n;

  while (n != 0) // knowing the number of digits in the number
  {
    n = n / 10;
    count = count + 1;

  }
  printf("The number of digits are: %d \n", count);
  float loop = 1.0 f;
  for (int k = 1; k <= count; k++) {
    loop *= 10.0;
  }
  for (float i = 10.0; i <= loop; i = i * 10.0) // loop to find out the sum of numbers
  {
    float b = a / i;
    int c = a / i;
    float d = b - c;
    int e = d * 10;
    x = x + e;

  }
  printf("The sum of digits is: %d", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following program :

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{

```
int N, rest, quot, sign = 1;

int sumDigits = 0;



printf("Please enter a value N > 0 :\n");

scanf("%d", &N);



if (N < 0)

{

    sign = -1;

    N = -N;

}



quot = N;
```

do

```
{

    rest = quot % 10;

    sumDigits += rest;

    quot = quot / 10;

} while (quot != 0);



printf("the sum of the digits of %d = %d\n", sign * N, sumDigits);

return 0;
```

}